# Unable to post multiple images to API formdata in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am adding multiple images in different rows and getting the required array in
console. But when I send the files I only files one row are being sent and for rest
rows the files show as undefined in the backend.

```
  const [images,setImages] = useState([]);

  const imageHandler = (e) => {
    const multiple = e.target.files;
    setImages(prev => {
        return [...prev,multiple]
    })
}

  useEffect(() => {
    console.clear();
    images.length && console.log(images)
  },[images]) 

The problem is in the code below. I want to append multiple files of one row as one 
array for one row. Please suggest what I am doing wrong?

images.forEach((file) => {
      formdata.append('files', file)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it new Key for each file found in the array as:

```
values?.delete_pictures?.forEach((id, ind) => {
      data.append(`delete_pictures[${ind}]`, id);
});
```

Comment: Tried. But it does not work.